# What is the correct way of initializing react component with data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm learning react.js with rails using `react-rails`.
App is basically list of sport events.

What is better way of initializing my main component with data?

1. `<%= react_component('EventsBox', {url: events_path(format: 'json')}, {prerender: true)} %>`

And then make an ajax request to upload data from this url in `componentDidMount`.

or

2. send it directly via props?

`<%= react_component('EventsBox',{data: Event.all.as_json},{prerender: true)} %>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be prerendered with data, then option 2 is what you want.